# Got this error while trying to fetch data from MongoDB. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, mongodb

I'm trying to fetch articles data from mongodb by GET request using AJAX, but the data result gives me "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**".
This is the client-side code

```
(function () {
    var ulArtikel = document.getElementById('ulArtikel');
    var apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/:id/artikel';
    ajaxFunctions.ready(ajaxFunctions.ajaxRequest('GET', apiUrl, function (data) {
        var articleObject = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(articleObject);
        for (var i=0; i<articleObject.length; i++) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            var node = document.createTextNode(articleObject[i].title);
            li.appendChild(node);
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }
    }));
})();
```

This is the request handler code

```
var Article = require('../models/articles.js');
function ArticleHandler() {
    this.getArticles = function (req, res) {
        Article.find().exec( function (err, result) {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            res.json(result);
        });
    };
}
module.exports = ArticleHandler;
```

the request is invoke from this route

```
app.route('/api/:id/artikel')
        .get(isLoggedIn, articleHandler.getArticles);
```

Comment: You data seems to be `invalid json`

Comment: Can you please show what is returned from server ?

Comment: @Leopard I try to append the result into li without JSON.parse, it gives me hundreds of undefined objects on the html

Comment: Can you please show the data ?

Comment: @Leopard the data are just hundreds of "undefined" words shows up on my html page

Comment: You can see data in browser console and add it here